# After how many days we should pluck coffee beans from its tree?

Tags: farming

After how many days we should pluck coffee beans from its tree for coffee production?

Answer (score 2):

According to two sources I have read [[1](https://www.longbottomcoffee.com/coffee-101/the-coffee-bean/life-cycle-of-the-coffee-bean.html), [2](http://www.coffeeresearch.org/coffee/homegrowing.htm)], it takes around 5 years for a coffee tree to reach maturity and it will then yield approximately one pound of beans per year. In further depth, fresh coffee beans should germinate within 2-3 months while old ones can take up to 6.